# How to handle duplicate entry for email error?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a form where admin can add users. When I submit form with some email that exist in database I get error saying

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'mail@mail.com' for key 'users_email_unique'

I want to avoid that error and instead to get for example warning "mail is taken" or something similar. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

UserController.php

```
public function store(StoreUserInfo $data)
{
    $data->validated();

    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'city' => $data['city']
    ]);

     return redirect()
        ->route('admin.users')
        ->with('message', 'User created successfully');
}
```

StoreUserInfo.php

```
public function rules()
{
    $emailid = (Auth::user()->roles()->first()->name == 'admin')
        ? (isset($this->user->id)?$this->user->id:Auth::user()->id) : Auth::user()->id;

    return [

        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,' . $emailid],
        'city' => ['required', 'exists:cities,city']
    ];
}
```

register.blade.php

```
<form id="form"method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.user.store') }}">

    @csrf

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" required autocomplete="first_name" autofocus>

            @error('first_name')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="last_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('last_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="last_name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}" required autocomplete="last_name" autofocus>

                @error('last_name')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

            @error('email')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

            @error('password')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="city" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Select City') }}</label>

            <input name="city" list="result" id="input" value="{{ old('city') }}" class="form-control  @error('city') is-invalid @enderror col-sm-6 custom-select custom-select-sm"required autocomplete="city">
            <datalist id="result">
            </datalist>

            @error('city')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
    </div>

</form>
```

users table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check like this way.

```
public function store(StoreUserInfo $data)
{
    $data->validated();

  $email = User::where('email',$data['email'])->first();
 if($email){
    return redirect()
    ->route('admin.users')
    ->with('message', 'Email is already exists.');
 }

$user = User::create([
    'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    'city' => $data['city']
]);

 return redirect()
    ->route('admin.users')
    ->with('message', 'User created successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be handled a few different ways, but for readability and to keep the number of queries to a minimum I would change the `create()` to a `firstOrCreate()` and use laravels built in `wasRecentlyCreated` to see if the user is new.

```
 $user = User::firstOrCreate([
        'email' => $data['email'],
    ], [
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'city' => $data['city']
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
]);
```

Since you can pass two arrays to `firstOrCreate`, it will return the first record that matches the email, or creates a new one with the attributes you pass to it. You can then use `wasRecentlyCreated` to check if it was a new record or if one already existed.

```
if($user->wasRecentlyCreated){
    return whatever you need if it is a new user 
}
else{
   return user was already in the database
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create validator with Rule 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

```
$messages = [
    'email.unique' = 'Email taken',
];

Validator::make($email, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use($email) {
            return $query->where('email', $email);
        }),
    ],
],
$messages
);
```

This will help you to manage all you validations, not only one. If you add the other validations you will return to the user all error, not only email error.